# How to pass on regex argument to another script through SSH

Tags: python, regex, ssh

I want to call a python script, *script1.py*, which takes a regex string as argument. This script then connects to another server and calls a *script2.py*.

**script1.py**:

```
regex = sys.argv[1]
log = os.popen('ssh otherserver python /home/log/scripts/script2.py \"%s\"' % regex)
for line in log:
    print line.strip()
log.close()
```

**script2.py**:

```
regex = re.compile(sys.argv[1])
for line in ['[1','[  2]',' a ']:
    if regex.search(line):
        print line.strip()
```

The problem I'm running into is that parentheses are breaking the script when run through SSH.
This works:

> [foo@bar scripts]$ python script1.py ".*"
>   [1
>   [  2]
>   a

This doesn't:

> [foo@bar scripts]$ python script1.py "(.*)"
>   bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>
>   bash: -c: line 0:`python /home/log/scripts/script2.py (.*)'

Why isn't the argument in the second example escaped? This does not occur if I call *script2.py* locally without SSH.

### Update with solution:

Turns out the solution was using subprocess, but passing arguments didn't work, so I had to format the last argument to include the escaped regex:

```
log = subprocess.check_output(['ssh', 'eu1', 'nice', 'python', '/home/log/scripts/script2.py \"%s\"' % regex])
print log.strip()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(['ssh', 'otherserver', 'python', '/home/log/scripts/script2.py', regex])
```

Comment: Thanks! Updated with solution :)